# I'm trying to build a Neural Network in python

Tags: neural-network

I'm trying to build a neural network and am following a tutorial.

What do those two lines mean?

```
    syn0 = 2*np.random.random((3,4)) -1
    syn1 = 2*np.random.random((4,1)) -1
```

Specifically, Those values (3,4 | 4,1)

I just don't get it...
I think I know what the first synapse's values mean, but not the 2nd one...

Answer (score 0):

[`np.random.random`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.random.html) creates an array of random values between 0 and 1 - the parameter it takes is the desired shape of the array, which is what `(3,4)` and `(4,1)` are in your example.

Simple random weight initialisation is sufficient to train your neural network, but [initialising them with a mean of 0 speeds up training](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-initialize-weights-in-a-neural-net-so-it-performs-well-3e9302d4490f), which is what `2*np.random.random((3,4)) -1` does:

```
np.random.random((3,4)) // array with values in range [0, 1) and mean of 0.5
```

```
2 * np.random.random((3,4)) // array with values in range [0, 2) and mean of 1
```

```
2 * np.random.random((3,4)) - 1 // array with values in range [-1, 1) and mean of 0
```